# Windows 10 TensorFlow cannot detect Nvidia GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

My Dell laptop has Windows 10 installed and I use it to code in Python.

TensorFlow and Keras do not seem to have a problem since I am able to find the version.

```
nvidia-smi and nvcc --version
```

But TensorFlow is not ok.
Here is my code.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('CPU'))
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

Here is the output:

```bash
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]
[]
```

I hope someone can help me, thanks a lot.